# CakePHP - ACL and Setting ACO

Tags: cakephp, acl

I'm implementing ACL in a CakePHP app that I have and I seem to be struggling with setting up ACOs. I've been following the [Simple ACL Controlled Application](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html) tutorial and I've set up the aros, acos and aros_acos tables fine, and adding AROs via groups/add and users/add works great - they get added to the aros table.

Now I'm at the part where I have to set up ACOs, and I'm a bit lost if I'm honest. The tutorial uses a console plugin to register the ACOs. However, this [Net Tuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-cakephps-access-control-lists/) adds them manually using:

```
$aco = new Aco();  
$aco->create();  
$aco->save(array(  
    'model' => 'User',  
    'foreign_key' => null,  
    'parent_id' => null,  
    'alias' => 'User'  
));  
$aco->create();  
$aco->save(array(  
   'model' => 'Post',  
   'foreign_key' => null,  
   'parent_id' => null,  
   'alias' => 'Post'  
));
```

Using this manual code we're creating ACOs for the User and Post controllers as a whole - I get that. What if I wanted to then set up an ACO for say the **edit** action for the user controller? How would that syntax look?

I think I'd rather just code it like this within an install_aco() function in a controller than use the plugin you see.

Or...couldn't I just control access to controller/actions using Auth without using the ACL at all? For example, I could add a 'role' field to the users table, and then in the beforeFilter() of controllers I could check the role, and redirect the user if they don't have the correct role/permission. What would be the downside to this?

Anyway, I'd really appreciate some help here and many thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following plugin made things really easy for me to implement ACL into my CakePHP application:

http://www.alaxos.net/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl_2.0

It provides a really good interface for not only setting permissions as you mentioned (**edit** action for the User controller), but all ACOs found throughout your application.

You also mentioned taking the non-ACL approach as well, and what you suggest should work fine. Check out this page on the CakePHP site, noting the isAuthorized() parts:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

I've personally used both ways, but have found ACL (using the above plugin) to be easier to manage.

Comment: Hi @Ryan, Thanks very much for the response. I think for this app then I'm going to run with just controlling the access by writing some role checks and using the Auth component without ACL. I'll need to be doing checks anyway for controlling access at a user/record level so it's seems appropriate to do this. Thanks again.

Comment: The plugin is buggy with latest cakephp